# Is there a faster alternative to systeminfo.exe on Windows?

Tags: windows, configuration

I'm using systeminfo.exe from my application diagnostics module to obtain computer hardware configuration. But systeminfo may take dozens of seconds to complete. Is there an alternative built-in tool that can get hardware info faster and supports all recent Windows versions?

Systeminfo also gets a lot of info that I do not need, like installed hotfixes. But its command line help doesn't provide any switches that can be used to configure what information should be collected.

The information I need is: OS version and info about processor, memory, hard disks, network cards. So, basically what systeminfo.exe provides, except for hotfixes.

Comment: have you taken a look at wmic?

Comment: It would help if you detailed exactly which information you want.

Comment: wmic looks promising, but I see it cannot be run without admin permissions, on xp at least.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered BGInfo?

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897557.aspx

One feature in particular that I think you might find useful is the following

File|Database: Specifies a .XLS, .MDB or .TXT file or a connection string to an SQL database that BGInfo should use to store the information it generates. Use this to collect a history of one or more systems on your network. You must ensure that all systems that access the file have the same version of MDAC and JET database support installed. It is recommended you use at least MDAC 2.5 and JET 4.0. If specifying an XLS file the file must already exist.

BGInfo is also very configurable, and you can create custom WMI queries to collect various items that are not a part of the standard display options in BGInfo.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but I came across it while looking for answers to the same question.

From the Command Prompt:

systeminfo | find /V /I "hotfix" | find /V "KB"

This gives you systeminfo without the hotfixes and works really well in a batch that loops through logging everything.

Comment: I like this. It's quick an dirty, for it to be useful though it needs to be put into a bat file so we don't have to type this out all the time

Comment: I needed this and I wanted to bring it back to my laptop from various servers... I could not do a RPC which was a NO from group policies but here is the next best thing.. Where I declare local drives on my laptop for Remote Desktop then I run from the CMD prompt. ( By the way 'find' will not work in Powershell )
 Enjoy 

systeminfo | find /V /I "hotfix" | find /V "KB" > \\tsclient\C\HankShare\SYSTEMINFO_Reports\%COMPUTERNAME%_reports.txt